# How to iterate List using RxJava 2.1.7 Observable for Maven project?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am working on maven app where the version of Rx Library i'm using here is `2.1.7`.
I have following code

```
Observable.just(listData).flatMap(data -> data)
```

The purpose of this trivial code is to iterate through `listData` object which is `data`. The problem is the `data` type is still `List` hence i can not access the attribute of `data` using

```
flatMap(data -> data.getAttribute)
```

In simple way, i just wanna this code

```
Observable.just(listData).flatMap(data -> data)
```

works just as Java8 Lambda Map like this

```
listData.map(data -> data.getAttribute)
```

I'm just exploring this library, so i have limited knowledge to this.
Also some code on youtube and blogs just didn't help, i think it's because the version of their's different to mine.
Any comments would be helpful, please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate list with RxJava/RxAndroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746218/iterate-list-with-rxjava-rxandroid)

Comment: `Observable.from`?

Comment: @DariaPydorenko already tried it sir, not working at all. The version is different i guess

Comment: @BoristheSpider there are no `Observable.from` in this version sir.

Comment: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#fromIterable-java.lang.Iterable-

Comment: @BoristheSpider that one is the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want `Observable.fromIterable(list)`?